# How to input digits and symbols in Tizen web app

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm trying to make input field, where I can enter IP address. If I use `type="number"` it is not possible to pick `.` symbol. But if I use `type="text"` there are some unnecessary keyboards are displayed, such as letters, voice input, emojis that I don't want to have. I want to have something like two pages with digits and symbols. Any suggestions?

**index.html**

```
<div class="ui-page" id="page-text-input">
    <div class="ui-content text-input-content">
        <input id="ip" name="ip" placeholder="IP" type="number" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I verified your issue. I think this is not issue of keyboard or platform. Referring to https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attributes
the input field type="number" doesn't fit to IP address. This type is dedicated for floating numbers.
Apart from the fact that there is one separator for decimals in the number, it can be a point or a comma depending on the location / region settings.

Only solution what I see that you add four input fields with type number for each IP number class or use some widget like spin widget.

Best regards,
Tomasz

Comment: Thanks for the answer